# How to create a migration relationship in two separate databases in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have two separate projects with Laravel and I have two separate Databases.

I connect this databases in *config/database.php* and it's work fine.

But now I need to create a relationship between products from database1 to users from database2 ( call sellers in database1 ) but I need to save this migration in database1, How can I do this ?

I try this :

```
Schema::connection('database2')->create('product_seller', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('seller_id');
    $table->foreign('seller_id')->references('id')->on('sellers')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->primary(['product_id', 'seller_id']);

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

But in this case the table created in database2, and if I delete `connection('database2')` I get error because I don't have seller table in database1, But I have `Seller.php` model here who connected to users in database2

```
class Seller extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $connection = 'database2';
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = [...];
}
```

Comment: If it really are two seperated projects, I'd recommend creating an API in one project and call that API in the other.

Comment: @Daan You mean I send data from project2 and get them in project1 ?